# java.net.ConnectException : Connection timed out with spring boot application

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I deployed a springboot application on a linux VM. Then send the postman request (HTTP GET) to the endpoint. However, I got connection timed out while I'm NOT getting this error when I deployed it to another machine in the same network (LAN). What should be possible reasons this? How can I enable tomcat log for looking into details?

NOTE: this application connects to an external API which can be called by a curl with authentication on this same server.

```
2017-12-26 18:26:48.043 ERROR 13301 --- [.70-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.      [.[.[.[.c.r.t.c.JerseyConfig]  : Servlet.service() for servlet   [jp.co.rakuten.travel.controller.JerseyConfig] in context with path   [/home] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~. [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1974) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:492) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:441) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1396) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1178) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1596) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:160) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-2.9.0.jar:na]
at jp.co.rakuten.travel.api.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at jp.co.rakuten.travel.service.TestSuiteServiceImpl.getProjectNameBySuiteID(TestSuiteServiceImpl.java:415) ~[classes/:na]
at jp.co.rakuten.travel.controller.MtmController.syncTestsBySuiteId(MtmController.java:195) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) ~[jersey-common-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072) ~[jersey-server-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.16.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.16.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
```

Comment: Does this request work with a browser ?

Comment: check your firewall?

Comment: @berger, when I deployed the service on another machine then request, it works with the browser

Comment: I got the solution. The solution is to set system proxy inside the Java application using System.setPropterty(...).